# Change scale in plot_model function

Tags: r, sjplot

I am trying to use the `plot_model()` function (`sjPlot` package) in R. However, it only allow me to use the minimum range of x-axis as -1 to 1. Since my estimates are very small, I would like to change the range to -0.2 to 0.2. I have tried this code:

```r
sjPlot::plot_model(lm_PMd2, 
                  axis.labels=c("TimeInterval", 
                                "FactorAnalyses_diff"),
                  show.values=TRUE, show.p=TRUE,
                  colors = "#ec7014", 
                  title="PMd", axis.lim = c(-0.2, 0.2)) +
 theme_bw()+ 
 theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
       text = element_text(size = 12))
```

Any insight is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Catherine, looking through the sjPlot source, it depends on the exact model you're plotting. Please provide a reproducible example including code for how `lm_PMd2` is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** you can do this (no reproducible example given, so I made one up):

```r
m1 <- lm(Murder ~ UrbanPop, data = USArrests)
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(m1) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.2, 0.2))
```

- you will get a message ("Scale for 'y' is already present ..."), which you can ignore
- it may be confusing that the code above tells ggplot to override the **y-axis** (rather than the x-axis, which is what it looks like on the plot): this is (I assume) because the package internally uses a `coord_flip()` specification.
- it's not obvious to me why `axis.lim = c(-0.2, 0.2)` doesn't do what you want — perhaps it's either a bug or confusingly documented?

> Numeric vector of length 2, defining the range of the plot
> axis. Depending on plot-type, may effect [sic] either x- or y-axis.
> For *Marginal Effects* plots, ‘axis.lim’ may also be a list
> of two vectors of length 2, defining axis limits for both the
> x and y axis.